# Junit 5 not detected

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, junit5

so, i'm trying to create a unit testing with Junit 5, but for some reason the test event were not received. I already removed Junit 4 from gradle dependencies.

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class TestTest {

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        println("Setup")
    }

    @Test
    fun testFoo() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

and my gradle dependencies for junit5:

```
 testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3'
 testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.3'
 testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.3'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this kind of behavior a few times and in my case, I missed specifying `useJunitPlatform()` for all `test` tasks (also see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_testing_basics)) like this (I suppose you're using groovy gradle DSL):

```
tasks.named('test', Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is just an educated guess - to be sure, you'd need to post more of your `build.gradle`-file, so I could reproduce your setup.

Comment: Sorry, i actually have solved it. When i ask this into the discord community server, the reason why it won't run on me is simply because Junit5 cannot run in android without 3rd party plugin. But, thanks for the answer

Comment: Alright, thanks for the additional information. Just as a note: Mentioning you are talking about Android Tests is essential when asking a question like yours, so adding the information to your question might still be helpful.

Comment: Pardon me, its because i think Junit5 is supposed to be working just fine on android, same as Junit4